# ISP with 115200 baud

Tags: isp

I have a serial ISP programmer of protocol type "stk500v1" which expects 115200 baud data rate. I have used it successfully with Atmel Studio by calling avrdude manually (custom tool) in the past. This just involves the avrdude option

> -b 115200

But recently I wanted to do use the Arduino software instead of Atmel Studio for a quick mockup. But everytime I try to "Upload with Programmer", the avrdude commandline includes the option

> -b 19200

and so the programming fails.

I can make it work by changing the hard wired serial rate in the programmer from 115200 to 19200, but then of course the programming is dead slow, which I don't want.

I have also looked for a baudrate entry for stk500v1 in "avrdude.conf", but didn't find any. How can I change the baud rate for "Upload with programmer" in the Arduino software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the `programmers.txt` file. (The one in `~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.21/`, *not* the one in `arduino-1.8.x/hardware/arduino/avr/`)

```
avrisp.name=AVR ISP
avrisp.communication=serial
avrisp.protocol=stk500v1
avrisp.program.protocol=stk500v1
avrisp.program.speed=115200
avrisp.program.tool=avrdude
avrisp.program.extra_params=-P{serial.port} -b{program.speed}
```

Add a `avrisp.program.speed` option, and pass this option as one of the `extra_params` to the command line call of avrdude.
It is then used on [line 112](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/b7c607663fecc232e598f2c0acf419ceb0b7078c/platform.txt#L112) of `platform.txt`:

```
tools.avrdude.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {program.verbose} {program.verify} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"
```

You could of course also make a copy of that avrisp entry, and add your own programmer, just give it a different name.

Comment: "programmers.txt" was the key! However I really had to change the one in "<progdir>/hardware/arduino/avr/". Probably it's because I am  using Windows 10, or probably because I am still on Arduino 1.6.7. Anyway, it works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: They changed the way the board manager works in 1.8.x, in the new versions, other boards (cores) you install are in the `~/.arduino15/packages` folder, including the standard AVR core. However, the old (1.6.x) hardware folder that you're using right now was not deleted, that's why I specifically added it. It's not a problem in 1.6.x, only newer versions.